# trying to get ec2 image list including blockDeviceMappings.snpshotID

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-iam

I need to get list of ec2 images including the **bloak device snapshot ID**, the list should include only the images belongs to me.
Till now i have managed to get the list of image iD without the extra information

In addtion, is there a way to get the list i own instead of adding my ID?

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2',aws_access_key_id = "ID",aws_secret_access_key = "ID",region_name = "eu-west-1")
filter=[{'Name':'owner-id','Values':['MY-ID']}]
count_aim = 1
for each_aim in ec2.images.filter(Filters=filter):
        print (each_aim)
        count_aim = count_aim + 1
print (count_aim)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should do:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', aws_access_key_id = 'dddddd', aws_secret_access_key="ggggfffff",region_name = "eu-west-1")

filter=[{'Name':'owner-id','Values':['123455']}]

block_ids = defaultdict(list)

for each_aim in ec2.images.filter(Filters=filter):
  for block_map in each_aim.block_device_mappings:
     block_ids[each_aim.id].append(block_map['Ebs']['SnapshotId'])
        
pprint(dict(block_ids))
```

Example output:

```
{'ami-02b8a850c975bb610': ['snap-02f277ce5b3b670fc'],
 'ami-06422cd44a94bab38': ['snap-0b0c9048f46992ee1']}
```